# Issue with Shap summary and bar plots generated in python script

Tags: python, shap

I am trying to save the shap summary plot and bar plot which are generated in a python script (not notebook). The plot gets generated but the features show up at the bottom and not on the sides. What am I missing here or any idea why there is this issue?

```
summary_plot = shap.summary_plot(shap_values, sample_df , show=False)
plt.savefig('temp3.png',format = "png",dpi = 150,bbox_inches = 'tight')
```

[image]

Comment: I found the issue.
The issue was because there was another plot being generated before the summary plot and I had to use plt.close()

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The issue was because there was another plot being generated before the summary plot and I had to use plt.close()

```
shap.bar_plot(shap_values[0], sample_shap_df.iloc[0],max_display=10)
plt.savefig('shap_bar_local.png',format = "png",dpi = 300,bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.close()
summary_plot = shap.summary_plot(shap_values, sample_shap_df, show=False)
plt.savefig('shap_summary_global.png',format = "png",dpi = 300,bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.close()
```